# Gradle Eclipse WTP: War file gets included in another war file

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle

I have two web (war) projects A and B.
B depends on A.
When I build B, A gets included as A.jar in WEB-INF of B as expected.

I am also using Gradle's eclipse and eclipseWtp plugins to generate Eclipse projects.
When I deploy B on Tomcat via Eclipse, and browse to the deployment directory, **I find A.war instead of A.jar in B's WEB-INF directory**. This obviously won't work. Besides, if A has other JAR dependencies, even those are not included in WEB-INF of B.

I have created a simple test for this. It can be downloaded from the link below.
Import the projects in eclipse and deploy them to tomcat via Eclipse. Then go to deployment location > WEB-INF/lib. You will find A.war there. It makes no sense to include a fully built war there. I was expecting A.jar (and any jars that A in turn depends on)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
}

project(':A') {

}

project(':B') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':A')
    }
}
```

[image: Open deployment location through eclipse]

[image: Contents of WEB-INF/lib in deployment location]

Download Link: [Test Projects and Build Script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/000yn6mm23keqio/gradletest.zip?dl=0)

Gradle Version:

Gradle 2.4
Build time: 2015-05-05 08:09:24 UTC
Build number: none
Revision: 5c9c3bc20ca1c281ac7972643f1e2d190f2c943c

Groovy: 2.3.10
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
JVM: 1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation 25.40-b25)
OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64

Comment: I actually have the VERY same issue right now with Gradle 3.5. Anybody help?

Comment: I ended up creating a separate project just for war. The war project only contains the static web files and other non-java files that go into WEB-INF directory. I  had managed to get it to work on Gradle 2.4 without changing project structure, but it was a little hacky and broke when I upgraded to Gradle 3.x. I thought it was less work to create a separate WAR project and that is what I did.

Comment: Also, when using direct deployment within Eclipse it sometimes does not include any third party jars. If this happens. Close eclipse. Run gradle cleanEclipse followed by gradle eclipse. To get rid of deployment issues. This happens on Gradle 3.x also. Could be an eclipse issue and not a grade one.

It may not be necessary to close eclipse always. Just refreshing the projects in eclipse after those two gradle operations should be enough.

Comment: Thumbrule: No project should have dependency on a WAR project. If that is the case, then split the WAR project into a WAR + JAR project where JAR contains the shared part and WAR contains web.xml, html, jsp etc. 

This is not a stated limitation of gradle but you'd run into issues if you don't follow it.

Comment: That is very good advice, thanks. My problem was that I was unintentionally applying the war plugin to all my subprojects, which caused the issues you describe above.